# Dropdown submenu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

My Javascript

```
var selectmenu = function(index, sub){
    $('.main-navigation-menu li:nth-child('+index+')').addclass('active');
}
```

In my view there are two li tags to select main menu and sub menu; so because of the above JS, it is always selecting a 1st main menu and the 1st sub menu; even when clicking the 2nd sub menu of the 1st main menu... anyone knows how to correct this behavior? Here I wanted to use the 'sub' variable and do something like this:

```
$('.sub-menu li:nth-child('+index+')').removeClass('active');
$('.sub-menu li:nth-child('+sub+')').addClass('active');
```

HTML

```
<ul class="main-navigation-menu ">
    @foreach (var menu in mainmenu) {
        var sublist = userContext.Menus.Where(m => m.Id == menu.Id);
        if (sublist.Count == 0){
            <li class="active open">
                <a href="@Url.Content(menu.MenuUrl)">
                    <span class="title"> @menu.Name </span>
                    <span class="selected"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
        else {
            <li class="main-menu-selection">
                <a href="@menu.MenuUrl">
                    <span class="title">@menu.Name</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
                    <span class="selected"></span>
                </a>
                @if (sublist.Count > 0) {
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        @foreach (var sub in sublist) {
                            <li class="sub-menu-selection">
                                <a href="@Url.Content(sub.MenuUrl)">
                                    <span class="title"> @sub.Name </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                         }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
        count++;
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to see what 'index' is being used by outputting it to the console? It could be that your function is always referencing index 1

Comment: no in the view page document.ready I'm passing selectmenu(x), x will change according to the menu item no

Comment: Some HTML that we can look at?

Comment: @Sam Battat html code added

Comment: How are you calling selectmenu? Since your submenu is within your main menu, when clicking the submenu (any item), you are also clicking on the first element of the main menu. You might need to call event. stopPropagation().

Comment: how to use stopPropagation?? can u show me the code??

Comment: sure. It's pretty simple. I will edit my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using stopPropagation:

```
$('.main-navigation-menu').on('click', '.sub-menu-selection', function(e){
  var index;

  e.stopPropagation();

  $('.min-navigation-menu .active').removeClass('active');
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
});
```

More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Hey @Tatermelon, please post this as a comment below the opening post, as it is not actually an answer

Comment: sorry I don't have enough reputation to post comments =(

Comment: add active and remove active also I'm doing through this selectmenu function

Comment: @Tartermelon with 50+ rep you can now leave comments anywhere